# How to check if an application is installed on iOS or Android phone using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, android, ios

I have a banking application in which I show the users a list of banks that they can choose from. I want to have the banks that the users use at the top of the list and I'm trying to check what banking apps does the user have installed on their phone.
I've been browsing SO for the past 2 days and I can't find a way to do this using Javascript.

Comment: I *highly doubt* any browser on any mobile device would provide this information to the JavaScript engine.

Comment: From a browser it will be impossible.  From a custom app written in Javascript-  at best you'd need to write a native module to provide the info, but I'm not sure if this is possible on either app anymore (it used to be possible on Android, but its now restricted for privacy reasons).